# The Matplotlib Result is Different From WolfarmAlpha

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, wolframalpha

I want to plot some equation in Matplotlib. But it has different result from Wolframalpha.

This is the equation:

> y = 10yt + y^2t + 20

The plot result in wolframalpha is:

[image: Result from wolframalpha]

But when I want to plot it in the matplotlib with these code

```
# Creating vectors X and Y
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
# Assuming α is 10
y = ((10*y*x)+((y**2)*x)+20)
# Create the plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
plt.plot(x, y)
```

The result is:
[image: Result from Matplotlib]

Any suggestion to modify to code so it has similar plot result as wolframalpha? Thank you

Comment: This statement: `y = ((10*y*x)+((y**2)*x)+20)` does not define an equation in python.  It makes an assignment.

Comment: For example, if `y` is currently 4, then `y = y**2` sets `y` to 16.  What you are wanting is to *solve for `y`*.  In that case, `y = y**2` means that `y` is 0 or 1.

Comment: There exist libraries for python that could make what you're doing in Mathematica possible, but it is much more difficult than in Mathematica.  Mathematica was made to do stuff like this.

Comment: @Him so to make it as equation the 'y' itself must nonexistent in the equation? Should I use the quadratic formula??

Comment: It looks like `t` is a function of `y`, so in this particular case a little manual algebra will suffice to get a plot, yes.

Comment: Or can you just import or connect to API of the wolfarmalpha to make the plot inside the jupyter notebook? @Him

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Him has suggested in the comments, `y = ((10*y*x)+((y**2)*x)+20)` won't describe a relationship, so much as make an assignment, so the fact that `y` appears on both sides of the equation makes this difficult.

It's not trivial to express y cleanly in terms of x, but it's relatively easy to express x in terms of y, and then graph that relationship, like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.linspace(-40, 40, 2000)

x = (y-20)*(((10*y)+(y**2))**-1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y, linestyle = 'None', marker = '.')
ax.set_xlim(left = -4, right = 4)
ax.grid()
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
```

Which produces the following result:

[image]

If you tried to plot this with a line instead of points, you'll get a big discontinuity as the asymptotic limbs try to join up

[image]

So you'd have to define the same function and evaluate it in three different ranges and plot them all so you don't get any crossovers.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y1 = np.linspace(-40, -10, 2000)
y2 = np.linspace(-10, 0, 2000)
y3 = np.linspace(0, 40, 2000)

x = lambda y: (y-20)*(((10*y)+(y**2))**-1)

y = np.hstack([y1, y2, y3])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x(y), y, linestyle = '-', color = 'b')

ax.set_xlim(left = -4, right = 4)
ax.grid()
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
```

Which produces this result, that you were after:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation. You help solve my problem. @Vineet